# boost:asio ::UnregisterWaitEx has not been declared

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, boost-asio

I am trying to compile a basic client/server C++ program in eclipse with `#include <boost/asio.hpp>` using MinGW on Win7 and I get:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type '::UnregisterWaitEx' has not been declared zion        line 106, external location: C:\boost_1_55_0\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_object_handle_service.ipp   C/C++ Problem
```

I included the path C:\boost_1_55_0 as well as the libraries boost_system and boost_asio.

Console output:

```
 14:00:24 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project boost_asio_test ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-IC:\\boost_1_55_0\\" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o server.o "..\\server.cpp" 
In file included from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/bind/bind.hpp:29:0,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/bind.hpp:22,
                 from ..\server.cpp:11:
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/bind/arg.hpp: In constructor 'boost::arg<I>::arg(const T&)':
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/bind/arg.hpp:37:22: warning: typedef 'T_must_be_placeholder' locally defined but not used [-Wunused-local-typedefs]
         typedef char T_must_be_placeholder[ I == is_placeholder<T>::value? 1: -1 ];
                      ^
In file included from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/win_object_handle_service.hpp:180:0,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/windows/object_handle_service.hpp:25,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/windows/basic_object_handle.hpp:27,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio.hpp:108,
                 from ..\server.cpp:12:
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp: In member function 'void boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::move_construct(boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::implementation_type&, boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::implementation_type&)':
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp:106:5: error: '::UnregisterWaitEx' has not been declared
     ::UnregisterWaitEx(impl.wait_handle_, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
     ^
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp: In member function 'void boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::move_assign(boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::implementation_type&, boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service&, boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::implementation_type&)':
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp:158:5: error: '::UnregisterWaitEx' has not been declared
     ::UnregisterWaitEx(impl.wait_handle_, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
     ^
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp: In member function 'void boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::destroy(boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::implementation_type&)':
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp:200:7: error: '::UnregisterWaitEx' has not been declared
       ::UnregisterWaitEx(wait_handle, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
       ^
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp: In member function 'boost::system::error_code boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::close(boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::implementation_type&, boost::system::error_code&)':
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp:251:7: error: '::UnregisterWaitEx' has not been declared
       ::UnregisterWaitEx(wait_handle, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
       ^
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp: In member function 'boost::system::error_code boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::cancel(boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::implementation_type&, boost::system::error_code&)':
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp:302:7: error: '::UnregisterWaitEx' has not been declared
       ::UnregisterWaitEx(wait_handle, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
       ^
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp: In static member function 'static void boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::wait_callback(PVOID, BOOLEAN)':
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_object_handle_service.ipp:402:5: error: '::UnregisterWaitEx' has not been declared
     ::UnregisterWaitEx(impl->wait_handle_, NULL);
     ^
In file included from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_tss_ptr.ipp:24:0,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/win_tss_ptr.hpp:76,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/tss_ptr.hpp:25,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/call_stack.hpp:20,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/impl/handler_alloc_hook.ipp:19,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/handler_alloc_hook.hpp:80,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/handler_alloc_helpers.hpp:21,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:19,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/wrapped_handler.hpp:18,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:24,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from ..\server.cpp:12:
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/error.hpp: At global scope:
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/error.hpp:252:45: warning: 'boost::asio::error::system_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static const boost::system::error_category& system_category
                                             ^
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/error.hpp:254:45: warning: 'boost::asio::error::netdb_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static const boost::system::error_category& netdb_category
                                             ^
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/error.hpp:256:45: warning: 'boost::asio::error::addrinfo_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static const boost::system::error_category& addrinfo_category
                                             ^
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/error.hpp:258:45: warning: 'boost::asio::error::misc_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static const boost::system::error_category& misc_category
                                             ^
In file included from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:28:0,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from ..\server.cpp:12:
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/asio/detail/winsock_init.hpp:116:30: warning: 'boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_instance' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
 static const winsock_init<>& winsock_init_instance = winsock_init<>(false);
                              ^
In file included from ..\server.cpp:9:0:
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222:36: warning: 'boost::system::posix_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
     static const error_category &  posix_category = generic_category();
                                    ^
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223:36: warning: 'boost::system::errno_ecat' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
     static const error_category &  errno_ecat     = generic_category();
                                    ^
C:\boost_1_55_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224:36: warning: 'boost::system::native_ecat' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
     static const error_category &  native_ecat    = system_category();
                                    ^

14:00:27 Build Finished (took 2s.579ms)
```

I tried looking in the .ipp but couldn't find anything very helpful. Something isn't declared but I am not sure what and nothing stands out in the boost.org documentation.

I haven't actually tried to implement any other boost code yet as it is not compiling even now but that might be what needs to be done?

The code I have now is a working client/server using winsock2 but I'd like to have it work on linux as well. Perhaps there is a conflict with the winsock2 code and boost::asio?

Comment: UnregisterWaitEx is a Win32 API function.  windows.h should declare it, but it seems to not be available.

Comment: I added symbol: _WIN32_WINNT val: 0x0601 to the project and that mitigated the UnregisterWaitEx issue. boost_asio and boost_system are not known libraries seemingly and I am now running into: 'WSAPOLLFD' was not declared in this scope referencing mswsock.h which I am not currently including myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For eclipse, add symbol: _WIN32_WINNT val: 0x0601 (or for your windows system: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to resolve the primary issue.

The WSAPOLLFD issue is due to: https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/9246 && http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2049/ which is patched by adding:

```
typedef struct pollfd {
  SOCKET fd;
  short  events;
  short  revents;
} WSAPOLLFD, *PWSAPOLLFD, *LPWSAPOLLFD;
```

to winsock2.h.

Comment: Why adding `_WIN32_WINNT`? Could you explain how this resolves the is issue of `UnregisterWaitEx()` not being declared? (will up vote when explained in your answer)

Comment: I don't know conclusively but my hunch is that the declaration of UnregisterWaitEx() is based on a macro dependent on the definition of the particular windows version.