# Error while using Boost Asio

Tags: c++, boost, mingw, boost-asio, codeblocks

I get "::UnregisterWaitEx is not declared" inside win_object_handle_service.ipp whenever I try to include < boost/asio.hpp > into my code.

Currently I am using Code::Blocks,  MinGW compiler (which didn't come bundled with IDE) on Windows 8.1.

Boost is built outside of mingw include folder, though is included in project settings.

Exact errors I am getting :

```
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_object_handle_service.ipp||In member   function 'void       boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::move_construct(boost::asio::deta il::win_object_handle_service::implementation_type&,  boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::implementation_type&)':|
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_object_handle_service.ipp|106|error: '::UnregisterWaitEx' has not been declared|
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_object_handle_service.ipp||In member function 'void     boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::move_assign(boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::implementation_type&, boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service&, boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::implementation_type&)':|
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_object_handle_service.ipp|158|error: '::UnregisterWaitEx' has not been declared|
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_object_handle_service.ipp||In member function 'void boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::destroy(boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::implementation_type&)':|
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_object_handle_service.ipp|200|error: '::UnregisterWaitEx' has not been declared|
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_object_handle_service.ipp||In member function 'boost::system::error_code boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::close(boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::implementation_type&, boost::system::error_code&)':|
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_object_handle_service.ipp|251|error: '::UnregisterWaitEx' has not been declared|
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_object_handle_service.ipp||In member function 'boost::system::error_code boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::cancel(boost::asio::detail::win_object_handle_service::implementation_type&, boost::system::error_code&)':|
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_object_handle_service.ipp|302|error: '::UnregisterWaitEx' has not been declared|
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\detail\impl\win_object_handle_service.ipp|402|error: '::UnregisterWaitEx' has not been declared|
boost_1_58_0\boost\system\error_code.hpp|221|warning: 'boost::system::posix_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
boost_1_58_0\boost\system\error_code.hpp|222|warning: 'boost::system::errno_ecat' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
boost_1_58_0\boost\system\error_code.hpp|223|warning: 'boost::system::native_ecat' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\error.hpp|258|warning: 'boost::asio::error::system_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\error.hpp|260|warning: 'boost::asio::error::netdb_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\error.hpp|262|warning: 'boost::asio::error::addrinfo_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\error.hpp|264|warning: 'boost::asio::error::misc_category' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\detail\winsock_init.hpp|116|warning:    'boost::asio::detail::winsock_init_instance' defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]|
```

What I've tried:

1. Set _WIN32_WINNT to 0x0601 (Just one more warning added)
2. Added struct pollfd to winsock2.h as instructed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957727/boostasio-unregisterwaitex-has-not-been-declared) (nothing happens)
3. Linked boost regex, system and thread libraries (or at least tried to)

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed this error by adding "-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 -DWINVER=0x0501" to both compilers linker options (in C::B) and #defines.
Guess I added _WIN32_WINNT somehow wrong.